# Facebook SDK for Android Cannot Resolve CallbackManager.registerCallback

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have been working to get Facebook SDK 4.0.1 running on Android but I have not been able to get the `LoginButton` to cause a login screen to open.

In the XML for my screen I have:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                        android:id="@+id/myLoginButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                        />
```

Then in my Activity I have:

```
CallbackManager callbackManager;
LoginButton loginButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MainActivity.localyticsSession.tagEvent("Sign In");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(R.layout.app_user_loginactivity);
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        // Initialize the Facebook LoginButton
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.myLoginButton);
        //loginButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // this works
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");

        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
                Log.i("LoginActivity","FB Login Success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
                Log.i("LoginActivity","FB Login Cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
                Log.i("LoginActivity","FB Login Error");
            }
        });
    }
```

When I tap the `LoginButton` it blinks like it is reacting, but the login screen does not appear.

**Update**

Android Studio is giving me a message that says `Cannot resolve method registerCallback`. I looked in `com.facebook.CallbackManager` which then imports `com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl`

`CallbackManagerImpl.java` contains this method:

```
public void registerCallback(int requestCode, Callback callback) {
        Validate.notNull(callback, "callback");
        callbacks.put(requestCode, callback);
}
```

I added `callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();` to my code, but that is not making a difference.

Comment: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1   u have this as dependency in build.gradle ... along with "mavencentral()" in repositories within build.gradle? do a clean / resync

Comment: + for the previous comment, in my case "sync project with gradle files" resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

where is the "onClick()" implementation for the FB logon button?

if its in the widget class then you need to drill-down into what is being called on the button click event....

below is sample from a more complex example (git parselogin-ui) but it gives the idea of what u are missing...

```
facebookLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    loadingStart(false); // Facebook login pop-up already has a spinner
    if (config.isFacebookLoginNeedPublishPermissions()) {
      ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithPublishPermissionsInBackground(getActivity(),
              config.getFacebookLoginPermissions(), facebookLoginCallbackV4);
    } else {
      ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(getActivity(),
              config.getFacebookLoginPermissions(), facebookLoginCallbackV4);
    }
  }
});
```

[see here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/blob/master/ParseLoginUI/src/com/parse/ui/ParseLoginFragment.java) @292

Comment: I will have to look in the morning. I thought the Facebook SDK would take care of this, on iOS I think having the item assigned as a LoginButton was enough for it to know to open the login screen.

Comment: Look into the widget. Button behavior may be define there

Comment: There is an `onClick` method in the widget file. I added a Log and can see it is registering the click. Down the rabbit hole I go ...

Comment: Did u upgrade fm FB 3 to FB 4 sdk.?  Make sure u are not colliding w older version of the sdk.

Comment: Something was busted with my Facebook SDK 4.0 files, re-copied all the files and everything started working.